# Mostrar itens da lista filtrando por date.today()

Tags: python, django, django-templates

tenho uma lista que ordeno pela `position` na minha `models.py`, porém tenho o campo `start_date` que quero usar como validador para que o item esteja visível ou não. Porém não esta dando certo:

***views.py***:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from datetime import date
from .models import *
from .forms import *
import requests

def videos_list(request):

    if 'lead_id' in request.session:
        videos = Video.objects.order_by("position").all()
        for video in videos:
            print(video.title)
            if video.start_date < date.today():
                print(True)
                show_video = True
            else:
                print(False)
                show_video = False

        return render(request, 'videos-list.html', {'videos': videos, 'show_video': show_video})

    return redirect('registrations:create_lead')
```

no *console*:

`Programe ou seja programado - Episódio 01
True
Programa ou seja programado - Episódio 02
True
Programe ou seja programado - Episódio 03
False`

Entendi que no final do looping ele deixa a minha variável `show_video` como False e por isso que meu *template* fica vazio

***video-list.html***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        {% for video in videos %}
        {% if show_video %}
        <div>
            <h1>
                {{video.title}}
            </h1>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{video.url}}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p>
                {{video.description}}
            </p>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém não estou entendendo como fazer de outra forma, será que alguém consegue me dar essa força ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa de um atributo `show_video` relacionado com cada objeto `Video` que você envia para o template.

Se não fosse um paradigma orientado a objetos, você poderia criar uma lista, com o valor de `show_video` relativo a cada vídeo, e usar o `zip` do Python no seu `for` dentro do template -

```
    ...
    show_videos = []
    for video in videos:
        print(video.title)
        show_videos.append(video.start_date < date.today()_  # True ou False
```

E aí teria que colocar a lógica de percorrer essa lista e a lista de videos em paralelo no template. Felizmente, isso não é necessário.

Como é OO, e o Python aceita atributos a mais dentro dos objetos, você pode também simplesmente embutir um atributo extra nos vídeos, antes de chamar o template:

```
    ... 
    for video in videos:
        print(video.title)
        if video.start_date < date.today():
            video.show_video = True
        else:
            video.show_video = False
    ...
    # e no template:
    {% if video.show_video %}
```

Mas melhor ainda, Python tem as properties - que permitem que propriedades que podem ser calculadas dinâmicamente com código funcionem, pra quem está usando o objeto, como se fossem um atributo.

Isso significa que você pode colocar o atributo `show_video` como uma property na classe vídeo - é diferente de um atributo que é uma instância de um `Field` do django - ele não é gravado no banco de dados. E aí, você coloca a mesma lógica que está na sua view, direto no model:

```
from datetime import date

class Video(models.Model):
    ...
    # campos do ORM
    # 
    ...
    @property
    def show_video(self):
          # o valor da expressão já é um boolean, ou seja True ou False:
          return self.start_date < date.today():
```

Como essa é a única operação que você está fazendo no `for` da view, nem precisa mais dele - a view fica apenas:

```
def videos_list(request):

    if 'lead_id' in request.session:
        videos = Video.objects.order_by("position").all()

        return render(request, 'videos-list.html', {'videos': videos})
```

E no template, é só modificar o `if` como coloquei acima, para pegar o campo `show_video` direto do objeto video:

```
    {% if video.show_video %}
```

Comment: cara sou teu fã namoral, muito obrigado pela explicação cara, tava batendo a cabeça